# Retrieving firebase info based from a UID

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
// if im ride leader, fetch details from firebase using my UID for name ect.
@IBAction func RideLeaderSwitchOn(_ sender: Any) {
   // hide feild for other user search
    if RideLeaderSwitch.isOn{
        OtherRideLeaderFeild.isHidden = true
        // perform databse search for current user info
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        if let user = user{
            let uid = user.uid
            let docRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
                docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                   if let document = document, document.exists {
                       let property = document.get("firstName")
                    print("Document data: \(String(describing: property))")
                   } else {
                       print("Document does not exist")
                   }
               }
            }
        }else{
         // if im NOT ride lead, Get user to enter another users First and Last Name and do an firebase search for a matching user
        OtherRideLeaderFeild.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

[image: Database layout]

I am trying to get the first name of the current user signed in by matching the current UID to the one in firebase document and then pulling the first name only from it, when I use this query I get my "document does not exist" error, where am I going wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get any results because your document id is not the same as your user id. Instead create the query like this:

```
let docRef = db.collection("users")
               .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
               .getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
    print(snapshot.documents)
}
```

Or if you want your query to work by querying the document id, set the document id to be the same as your uid when you create the document.

```
db.collection("users").document(uid).setData(["item": "test"])
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I totally missed that the doc ID wasn't equal to the UID.

Comment: @Dread while this is a good answer. You should really be storing users with the documentId being the users UID. Queries are very 'heavy' and are slower than reading data directly. If the documentId is the users UID you can avoid the query completely as you can just read the node directly. It will also eliminate storing the UID within the document, which saves on reading those bytes in as well.

Comment: For me, `firebase.firestore().collection("users").document` is undefined...